# How to create variable and encode the variable value unix

Tags: bash, unix, sh

I created an sh file. 
I created a variable

test = "example"
bash: test: =: unary operator expected

Can anyone tell how to create a variable and assign value to it.

Second one how to encode url in unix

I tried different scenarios but not found the solution

urlencoee "gdh@"
bash: urlencode: command not found

Please suggest solution for these problems

Export var = "val"

Printing the value in console

Tell me how to avoid printing the export variable

Comment: We're going to have to take this in several steps.

Answer (score 0):

No spaces between the variable name, =, and value.

```
test="example"
```